# Can't add a mouse listener to a JScrollpane which contains a list

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a JScrollPane (myListScroll) that is added to a JPanel (which in turn is added to another JPanel before being added to a JFrame). This JScrollPane (myListScroll) consists of a list of strings. I want to be able to handle mouse events when clicking on the different items in this list.

In the code below I want to try if something happens if I click i the JScrollpane but nothing happens. What is wrong? Why is "test" not written?

```
            JScrollPane myListScrol = new JScrollPane(myList);
        myListScrol.getViewport().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                System.out.println("test");
            }
        });
```

Comment: You're adding your listener to the viewport which is behind everything. Why not add it to the viewportView instead? For better help, consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should click on the border of JScrollpane

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels- I have tried it without viewportView as well. How do you mean that the code should look like mok?

Comment: Sound like you just want a `ListSelectionListener`. See [Selecting Items in a JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#selection)

Answer (score 1):

I should have added the listener to myList and not to myListScrol.